# setting up classic asp site on iis7, site runs but can see server tags

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript

Hi I have been sent a classic asp site to set up on IIS7. Im too young to know anything abuout classic asp and i cant find any documentation about my problem online. I have installed asp and the classicasp *.asp handler is enabled. When i go to the site the homepage loads ok but i can see a server tag at the top of the page:

```
<!--#include file="cp/inc_func.asp"-->

<% 
OpenDB()
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/index.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
```

I can see the <% OpenDB() %> tag at the top of the page on the front end.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Had any luck seting up ASP Classic on your IIS server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means your code is NOT executed by the ASP Classic engine. This means that your ASP Classic setup in IIS may not be correct.

Try the following tutorial on setting up ASP Classic in IIS7:

[Running classic ASP on IIS 7](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/02/18/running-classic-asp-on-iis-7.aspx)

Let me know if this worked!

Also here are some common tips on running Classic ASP on IIS7:

[Tips for Classic ASP developers on IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx)