# My ASP classic site is rendering the code instead of the output, how can I fix it?

Tags: asp-classic, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting up classic asp site on iis7, site runs but can see server tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007587/setting-up-classic-asp-site-on-iis7-site-runs-but-can-see-server-tags)

I have some knowledge in HTML, PHP and CSS, but I am very new to ASP.

After I installed IIS on Windows 7, I wrote some ASP code `<% =time %>` and I saved the file as `test1.asp` in a new folder. I opened my browser and typed in `http://localhost/MyWeb/test1.asp` and I could successfully view this web page result.

When I put the same file in my hosted web site and I type `http://mywebsite.ca/test1.asp`, the web page browser show me the source code instead of the result.

What have I do wrong? Maybe I don’t understand the concept here.

Please anybody can explain me how to use correctly ASP files in a hosted web site.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: verify that your host provider supports asp.  Being an older technology you might find your host only supports ASP.NET

Comment: @perception Please [don't edit a question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10050074/4) unless you a familiar with what is being asked. Classic ASP is not the same as ASP.Net, corrected the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up extension mappings and make sure the ASP classic module is installed and enabled. Here is a blog post ([Running classic ASP on IIS 7](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/02/18/running-classic-asp-on-iis-7.aspx)) that describes what to do in detail.

Also, you need to make sure that the web host can support Classic ASP. That is a really old technology and it is somewhat likely you will need to port it to asp.net (which is usually pretty easy to do).

In fact, you should make sure that the web host is even running IIS at all.

Comment: In most cases web hosting companies running IIS, also have ASP Classic enabled since it is included with all versions IIS. You have to manually activate it though.