# How to run ASP site?

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows 7 laptop. On that laptop I installed Visual Studio 2010. I do know that I can't run classic ASP on VS, but...
I created a ASP.NET project in VS and ran it from the C: drive. I have my classic ASP site on the G: drive.
So what I tried is to use:

```
localhost:53345///G:/home/igor/myhomepage.asp
```

But I received an error 'Bad Request'.

Is there a way of doing what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: I found following file on my laptop: C:\Windows\winsxs\wow64_microsoft-windows-iis-legacysnapin_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_e76a70010017c66c\InetMgr6.exe, but when I ran it and then load the page from G: drive nothing happened as well. Still got the same error.

Comment: Have you setup a site in IIS and pointed it to the directory where your site is? ASP needs to be executed by a module within IIS.

Comment: Hi, Guido, Do you have a link where it is described? Or can you tell it here? I tried to run IIS snap-in found in the same directory, but I got error: MMC could not create snap-in. I am running Win7 Home 64-bit.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007587/setting-up-classic-asp-site-on-iis7-site-runs-but-can-see-server-tags/10009513#10009513). In contains some links to guides. That should get you up and running.

Comment: Igor, had any luck with the guide from my answer below? If som could you tag it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup the site so that the ASP Classic code is executed by the webserver.

Use the following guide for this:

[Running classic ASP on IIS 7](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/02/18/running-classic-asp-on-iis-7.aspx)

After you have setup ASP Classic for IIS, just add a site and point it to the directory where the ASP files are. In de default IIS setup you can also place you ASP files in the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` like Farhan suggested.

Comment: I do not know what that page says, because it is not available anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in IIS but your best shot at running ASP Classic code is to copy it to the **C:\inetpub\wwwroot** folder (use the drive letter that windows is installed on!)

Other than that creating a website in IIS and redirecting to your target driver and folder, might help but I wouldn't bet my dollars on backward compatibility of IIS :)

Comment: uhm... `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` could be any folder you point your site to. IIS 7 is fully compatible with ASP Classic. Only thing is you have to install the module. It is not installed by default.