# IIS is serving but not executing classic asp script

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I wrote a classic ASP script (.asp) for a customer a while back.  it was running on IIS v6.1 Windows 2003.  The customer contacted me and said they had a catastrophic server failure and restored from backup but my script isn't running now.  I logged onto their server to check it out and IIS is serving the file (I am prompted to save when I browse to the script) but not executing the script.

Several people's hands were in the server before they called me, I think this is probably a simple config setting someone tried before they figured out how to enable the "ASP" web server roll feature. But for the life of me I can't figure out how they did it.  this is obviously not the default behavior.  If I was trying to get this behavior I would add the .asp extension to the MIME types, but I checked and it isn't there.

What could cause IIS to serve the source of the ASP script without executing it?

Comment: See [setting up classic asp site on iis7, site runs but can see server tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10007587/205233) and related.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I am assuming your restored server is also windows server 2003 ... in that case you will go to the file\folder and the permissions and select execute permission to enable a server side script processor to handle that request. Been almost a decade that I have touched a 2003 server so I can’t give you the exact steps ... but, you want to enable script permissions on that folder(I think, don’t remember if it’s granular enough to drill down to a file). Also, why on earth are they still running server 2003? Is that version even supported yet?

If it’s IIS 7, you want to make sure your app pool is in Classic ASP mode first off. Then go to site and then the handler mapping section, click edit and configure it that way.